# A bug in react-native-maps when using onRegionChangeComplete only on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps and it seems like a bug only on iOS. 
If I call onRegionChangeComplete, iOS moves the screen down forever. My code is like below!

```js
class PickLocation extends Component {
  state = {
    userLocation: {
      latitude: 0,
      longitude: 0,
      latitudeDelta: 0.015,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0121
    },
    moved: false,
    firstTime: true
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    // Place the screen where user stands after loading
    this.whereAmI();
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  whereAmI = () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            userLocation: {
              ...prevState.userLocation,
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude
            }
          };
        });
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        alert("Getting current Location Failed!");
      }
    );
  };

  onRegionChangeCompleteHandler = region => {
    console.log(region);
    if (this.state.firstTime) {
      this.setState({
        firstTime: false
      });
      return;
    }

    this.setState({
      userLocation: region,
      moved: true
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          initialRegion={this.state.userLocation}
          region={this.state.userLocation}
          style={styles.map}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeCompleteHandler}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

I think this happens because the coordinates after regionChange is differ with actual coordinates.

Please help me to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no bug neither in `react-native-maps` nor `ios`, it is the natural way how `React` behave.

`Region props` fires all the time while `onRegionComplete props` only fires once after coords change.

The `map bouncing/moving marker non-stop` happens because calling `setState` takes some amount of time to update the `state` which leads to a conflict. You need to update map region after `onRegionComplete` with new coords while `region` still has the old coords, so the map moves to the new coords and `region` fires all the time forcing the map to return back to the old coords which leads also to fire again `onChangeComplete` and the map then starts bouncing between old and new coords forever.

Solution is

- **First** Remove `region={this.state.userLocation}` and don't use `region prop` again, its not only because its the cause of your problem its also because you don't need to control your map with state.
- **Second** separate `initialRegion` coords from `userLocation` coords, its also one of the bouncing problem, as `initialRegion` fires once with new coords when `Map Componenet` first mounts, while `region` has coords {0,0} (set by your state).
  So you do it that way

  ```
  state ={
    initialRegion: {} //empty object
    }


  whereAmI = () => {
       Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            position => {
            this.setState({
               initialRegion: position.coords
           });
           },
          err => {
           console.log(err);
           alert("Getting current Location Failed!");
           }
         );
      };

     ..... map props 

     initialRegion={this.state.initialRegion}
  ```

And `onRegionComplete` its safe to set `userLocation's state`.